# React Native Navigation: Only show tab label for focused item

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I'm just trying to conditionally show/hide the label for the Tab navigator's items based on if they are focused or not. I am able to change the icon's tint color like so:

```
tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
   const icon = <Image
     style={{
        width: 25,
        height: 25,
        tintColor: focused ? colors.primary : colors.inactive
     }}
     source={require('./assets/account.png');}
     /> ;

     return icon
```

But trying to change the showLabel boolean conditionally based on the same prop isn't working?

```
tabBarOptions={{
       activeTintColor: colors.primary,
       inactiveTintColor: colors.inactive,
       showLabel: ({ focused }) => {
         return focused ? true : false
       },
```

The labels appear for all items on the Tab bar.

Any/all help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
    <Tab.Navigator 
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => {
          return <Text style={{fontSize: 14, fontWeight: '600', color: colors.primary}}>{focused ? route.name : ""}</Text>
        },
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
          let iconSource;

          if (route.name === 'Map') {
            iconSource = require('./assets/public.png');
          } else if (route.name === 'List') {
            iconSource = require('./assets/numbered.png');
          } else if (route.name === 'Log') {
            iconSource = require('./assets/menu.png');
          } else if (route.name === 'Talk') {
            iconSource = require('./assets/chat.png');
          } else if (route.name === 'Account') {
            iconSource = require('./assets/account.png');
          } 

          const icon = <Image
            style={{
              width: 25,
              height: 25,
              tintColor: focused ? colors.primary : colors.inactive,
              marginTop: focused ? 5 : 15
            }}
            source={iconSource}
          /> ;

          return icon
        },
      })}
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple solution, just add the `shifting` prop or assign it to `true`

```
<Tab.Navigator
    ...
    shifting={true}
    ...
>
```

Again, tested only on `@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs` so can't guarantee on other tab navigations. See more [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator).

Comment: material bottom has different options than non-material bottom. This will not work